# Greek-letter enumerate in .cls file

Tags: environments, enumerate, document-classes

So I found a code for making a Greek-letter enumerate environment, which works totally fine in a normal LaTeX file but not in my .cls file. When I try to import my class (let's call it myclass for simplicity) I get a lot of errors and ** in the pdf file. This is the code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019 myclass]
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}
\RequirePackage{chemgreek,textgreek}
    \renewcommand*\alphgreek[1]{\expandafter\@alphgreek\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \renewcommand*\@alphgreek[1]{\csname chemgreek_int_to_greek:n\endcsname{#1}}
    \renewcommand*\Alphgreek[1]{\expandafter\@Alphgreek\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \renewcommand*\@Alphgreek[1]{\csname chemgreek_int_to_Greek:n\endcsname{#1}}
    \AddEnumerateCounter*{\alphgreek}{\@alphgreek}{\chemalpha}
    \AddEnumerateCounter*{\Alphgreek}{\@Alphgreek}{\chemAlpha}

    \newenvironment{greeklist}{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alphgreek*)]}{\end{enumerate}}
    \newenvironment{Greeklist}{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alphgreek*)]}{\end{enumerate}}

\endinput
```

I get errors and just the symbols ** vertically alligned in the pdf-file when I load myclass:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
hello this is not working
\end{document}
```

In the version I found it had `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the first part (around the \renew command and \AddEnumerateCounter). Do I need to rephraseit in order to use it for myclass.cls?

I found the code [here](https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/277117.html).

Comment: Well, these are some code fragments which undoubtedly some experts will be able to make sense of. However, if you want to make this accessible to a broader audience, and thus get more feedback, please consider providing a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: I second the suggestion made by @Schrödinger'scat.  But yes, it is absolutely necessary to surround this code by `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`; any command that contains an `@` requires this treatment to be properly recognized.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I edited so it works as a .cls file. However, the problem is not that the commands don't work in a normal document that starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}. The problem is that it doesn't work in my .cls file.

Comment: I am sorry, I find it hard to believe that it works as a class file (as is). Doesn't, say, `\renewcommand*\@alphgreek[1]{\csname chemgreek_int_to_greek:n\endcsname{#1}}` require additional packages?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat now it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacing your `\renewcommand*`s by `\newcommand*` and also loading enumitem,

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019 myclass]
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}
\RequirePackage{chemgreek,textgreek,enumitem}
\newcommand*\alphgreek[1]{\expandafter\@alphgreek\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@alphgreek[1]{\csname chemgreek_int_to_greek:n\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand*\Alphgreek[1]{\expandafter\@Alphgreek\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@Alphgreek[1]{\csname chemgreek_int_to_Greek:n\endcsname{#1}}
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\alphgreek}{\@alphgreek}{\chemalpha}
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\Alphgreek}{\@Alphgreek}{\chemAlpha}

\newenvironment{greeklist}{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alphgreek*)]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{Greeklist}{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alphgreek*)]}{\end{enumerate}}
\endinput
```

it works beautifully on my TeXLive2019 installation

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
hello this is now working
\begin{greeklist}
 \item anteater
 \item bear
 \item cow
\end{greeklist}
\begin{Greeklist}
 \item Anteater
 \item Bear
 \item Cow
\end{Greeklist}
\end{document}
```

[image]